# Android javamail and google account

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

In my app I using javamail for sending emails via smtp. All in all this works fine, but when I use a google-Mail-address then it probably doest not work. The reason is, that I have to enter my google account settings and allow the use to "unsecure apps" (I don't know the english expresion, in german it is called "Zugriff für weniger sichere Apps erlauben"). Now my question is, what do I have to do, that I do not need to allow this? How can my app become an "secure" app?

Comment: May be you are trying to use SMTP without SSL encryption? You should use SMTPS (SMTP with SSL) on port 465.

Comment: I use smtps on port 465....

Comment: Ok, then it must be that you use your Google password. Google usually uses AOuth tokens that are saved in the app. I am not sure if this authnetication method can be used with SMTPS. Storing your password may enable hacker to steal it. Therefore Google allows to use application specific passwords. You can generate one for mail access in the Google GUI. Use this password instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Gmail as your server and don't want to change your account settings to [allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps), you'll need to use [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).

Comment: is there a common used library to get this authentication token?

Comment: Google has some [Java code](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) that should help.